# Wordpress Twenty Thirteen overflow-x not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to paste some code into one of my blog posts. I am doing so by wrapping the code in the `<pre>` tags because I want to maintain formatting. I am aware that Twenty Thirteen is a fixed width template and as such the `<pre>` tags still get squished and formatting gets broken. I am able to manually set a width which works but stretches the post out extremely wide and also does not look correct. As a result I am trying to get the content to scroll in x once the text gets too wide but it doesn't actually do anything.

I am currently working with inline CSS before I modify my child template. The code I am attempting to use in my post looks like this:

```
<pre style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll;">
```

I've tried other combinations (with overflow being set to auto) but nothing works. This may be as a result of the theme itself but I'm not really sure what would be causing this to happen. The post itself can be found [HERE](http://www.boxheadproductions.com.au/adventures-in-text-building-a-text-adventure/). I've reverted my inline CSS back to the fixed width so it can be viewed correctly for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following styles to make it work:

```
pre{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap: normal;
    width: 604px !important;
}
```

`white-space: pre;` and `word-wrap: normal;` prevents the code from auto-wrapping at spaces.

The `width` needs `!important` to override the element style (if you want to force width).

Comment: Thank you that worked so I've added it to my child CSS style sheet and removed all in line formatting. I need to work on making the template wider later (as 600 pixels just doesn't feel right) but that is a job for another time.

Comment: Is there any trick to getting this overflow to show correctly on a smart device? The page loads correctly on the device (i.e it fits the view port) however I don't get any visible scroll bar at the bottom of the `<pre>` field and everything is squashed again. Note for reference I changed `width: 604px` to `width: 100%` in my CSS.

Comment: ??? I just tested, and it works great on Firefox OS, and on Firefox for Android, but not on Chrome for Android.  I don't have an iPhone to test with.  Maybe changing to `white-space: pre !important;` will fix it.

Comment: Not sure if it is a Safari specific thing but forcing `word-wrap: normal;` has fixed it on my device (iPhone 5) and doesn't appear to have broken it on my desktop either.